# Efficient implementation of Mixture of Expert Layer in Pytorch

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am trying to implement the a mixture of expert layer, similar to the one described in:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06538

Basically this layer have a number of sub-layers F_i(x_i) which process a projected version of the input. There is also a gating layer G_i(x_i) which is basically an attention mechanism over all sub-expert-layers:

sum(G_i(x_i)*F_i(x_i).

My Naive approach is to build a list for the sub-layers:

sublayer_list = nn.ModuleList()
for i in range(num_of_layer):
    sublayer_list.append(self.make_layer())

Then when applying this I use another for loop

out_list= []
for i,l in enumerate(sublayer_list):
    out_list.appned(l(input[i]))

However the addition of this Mixture-of-Expert layer slows training by almost 7 times (against one with MoE layer swapped for a similar-sized MLP). I am wondering if there are more efficient ways to implement this in pytorch? Many thanks!